# Count # of times a certain outcome appears when randomly selecting from a list of possible outcomes

Tags: python, list, random, generator

My code generates random outcomes of the list "outcomes". I am running batches of 10,000+, and I need a way to count the batches and total them at the bottom. How would I do this?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep
outcomes = ['TT','Tt','Tt','tt']
for x in range (0, 5):  
    b = "LOADING OUTCOMES" + "." * x
    print (b, end="\r") 
    time.sleep(0.5)
print("4 Possible Genetic Outcomes Will Be Shown. . . ") ; sleep(1)
for x in range (0, 10000):
    print(random.choice(outcomes))
    time.sleep(0.001)        
x=input("Done determining outcomes!! Press enter to close")
```

Comment: Copy your code in the question. It shouldn't be necessary to open an external link to know what's going on.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see what you already have so we can help improve your code.  Also, what are you wanting your code to do?  Print the total of each outcome?  TT - 1 Tt - 2 tt - 16 ?

Comment: I tried to post code but it didnt show properly so i posted a pciture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the code you provided in the screen shot. Here is how I would go about it. Check if this solution works for you. Next time please put the code inside the question itself and not as an image. It will attract more people to help you since they can just copy paste your code and help you out quicker instead of typing out your code themselves.

How I solved it:
have a dictionary already predefined with the possible choices from the list. Each time a choice appears, just increment the counter by 1. At the end print all the possibilities. You can use a loop to do this, but since there are only 3 elements I decided to just print them out.

```
import random
import time
from time import sleep

outcomes = ["TT", "Tt", "Tt", "tt"]
outcomesCount = {"TT":0, "Tt":0, "tt":0}

for x in range(0,5):
    b = "LOADING OUTCOMES" + "." * x
    print(b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
print("4 Possible Genetic Outcomes Will Be Shown. . . ")
sleep(1)

for x in range(0,10000):
    choice = (random.choice(outcomes))
    time.sleep(0.001)
    outcomesCount[choice] += 1
    print(choice) #This is something you were doing in original code. I would not do this because there are too many print statements, and will cause the program to run for a while.

print("The number of times each outcome appeared was: ")
print("TT : %s" %(outcomesCount["TT"]))
print("Tt : %s" %(outcomesCount["Tt"]))
print("tt : %s" %(outcomesCount["tt"]))
x = input("Done determining outcomes!! Press enter to close")
```

The output of running the above program was **note this is only the last print statements**:

```
The number of times each outcome appeared was: 

TT : 2484
Tt : 4946
tt : 2570
Done determining outcomes!! Press enter to close
```

**improvements:**
1. get rid of the sleep because you are just delaying the program execution. You don't need it there. If you want the user to see the loading message for a second of two, you can just add 1 pause at the end.

2. The sleep in the second for loop is not needed at all. This is a computer and is capable of doing amazing things. This is nothing compared to what it can handle.
3. dont print all the outcomes, as it is going to be printing 10000 different rows.

Good luck and hope this helped.

Comment: @KYHS, Glad I was able to help you. I also edited the question for people so in future they know what you meant. The question was not cleat at first.

Comment: Thanks man. Really clean and fast now. Also, for those wondering, this is such a crappy script because i originally made it to string a list of insults at my friend, the I realised I could do this for bio. - thats also why it has sleep. I wanted him to see an insult every couple seconds and didnt think to pull it

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
from random import choice

outcomes = ["TT", "Tt", "Tt", "tt"]

totals = Counter(choice(outcomes) for _ in range(10000))
```

which gives something like

```
Counter({'TT': 2528, 'Tt': 4914, 'tt': 2558})
```

Comment: Nice Solution. much cleaner then the one I provided.

Comment: How might I add this? i get errors when I run with this instead of deltas solution

Comment: script just shuts down, I dont remember the error. Ill x2 check

Comment: File "C:/Windows/System32/test1.py", line 41, in <module>
    totals = Counter(choice(outcomes) for _ in range(10000))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 523, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 610, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
  File "C:/Windows/System32/test1.py", line 41, in <genexpr>
    totals = Counter(choice(outcomes) for _ in range(10000))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: In my code, `choice` is a function; in yours, it is apparently a string.